# Is there a reason that might prevent Carles Puigdemont's extradition to Spain?

Tags: spain, extradition

According to [this article](https://sputniknews.com/europe/201803251062878851-puigemont-detention-germany-catalonia/), former Catalan President has just been detained in Germany:

> Former Catalan leader Carles Puigdemont has left Finland before the
>   country's police could arrest him in line with an arrest warrant
>   issued by Spain, Puigdemont's lawyer Jaume Alonso Cuevillas informed
>   earlier. The ex-head of Catalonia is currently being held at a police
>   station.
>
> A Spanish Supreme Court judge had reactivated an international arrest
>   warrant for Puigdemont on Friday while the latter was visiting
>   Finland.

So, his being detained seem to follow a perfectly legal process (i.e. EU recognized arrest warrant).

However, I am wondering if there is a mechanism which could prevent Spanish government from obtaining his extradition.

**Question:** Is there a reason that might prevent Carles Puigdemont's extradition to Spain?

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_offence_exception. But its application is dependant of what the detaining country considers "political offence". Belgium has a rather low bar and in the past has refused extradition of even members of terrorist organizations, which is why Puigdemont sought to be detained there. Now, I think that if Puigdemont is likely to be protected by German law is a legal question, but maybe there are other mechanisms available.

Comment: That sounds more like a legal question?

Comment: The legal side to this is explained [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslieferung_(Recht)) in German and amounts to the fact, that extradition necessitates that the offence needs to be illegal in both countries. "Rebellion" (with up to 30 years of prison linked to it) has no direct correspondence in the German legal system to my knowledge.

Comment: @sleske The veil between politics and the legal system seems a rather thin one sometimes? Law can never be absolute and the way it is practiced may well be quite politically motivated. I am new to this site but would rather err on the inclusive side regarding a separation of "law vs. politics"?

Comment: @FriedrichN.: True. On second thoughts, I think the question is simply unclear - asking for a "reason that might prevent Carles Puigdemont's extradition" is very broad. Is it asking about laws that prevent extradition? That would (IMHO) be off-topic. Is it asking about whether, why and how some politician or official could oppose the extradition? That would seem on-topic.

Comment: @Alexei: Could you clarify your question? What are you asking about - legal rules, official opinion, political motivation?

Comment: I am mostly interested in official opinion + political motivation since legal rules are mostly dealt with on Law.SE.